# Неожиданное поведение простого Python3 скрипта (изменение списка в цикле). Почему?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

У меня есть следующий простейший скрипт

```
inp = input().split()
print('inp', inp)
l = []
for elem in inp:
    l.append(int(elem))

print('initial: ', l)

for el in l:
    print(el)
    if el % 2 != 0:
        l.remove(el)

print('after removing odd numbers: ', l)
```

Первый инпут (строка):

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

вывод:

```
inp ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
initial:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
1
3
5
7
after removing odd numbers:  [2, 4, 6]
```

Второй инпут (строка):

```
10 8 5 3 1
```

вывод:

```
inp ['10', '8', '5', '3', '1']
initial:  [10, 8, 5, 3, 1]
10
8
5
1
after removing odd numbers:  [10, 8, 3]
```

Скриншот [здесь](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4_bX7nMU9_8QUpab1JwZTR3LTA/view?usp=sharing).

> 1й ввод/вывод
>
> 1) Почемы скрипт выводит только нечетные элементы? Он должен выводить все элементы.

---

> 2й ввод/вывод
>
> 1) Почему в выводе нет числа 3, только 10, 8, 5 и 1?
>
> 2) И, следовательно, почему конечный список содержит число 3?

Благодарю!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы проходитесь списком по циклу, который меняете. Это плохая идея. Когда вы удаляете текущий элемент в цикле из списка, внутри питона текущим неявно становится следующий элемент. А когда начинается следующая итерация, берётся снова следующий элемент, тем самым один элемент проскакивается.

Покажу наглядно на этом коде:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for x in a:
    a.remove(x)
```

Первая итерация до удаления — берётся элемент с индексом 0:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
 ^ - текущий элемент
```

Первая итерация после удаления (обращаю внимание, что значение переменной `x` никто не поменяет):

```
[2, 3, 4, 5]
 ^
```

Упс, мы неявно поменяли текущий элемент. Хотя в переменной `x` всё ещё содержится единица, по индексу 0 уже находится совсем другой элемент.

Вторая итерация — берётся элемент с индексом 1:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5]
    ^
```

Упс! Проскочили.

---

Как лечить?

Никогда не менять список, по которому проходитесь циклом. Например, сделать его копию и запустить цикл уже по копии:

```
l_copy = l[:]
for el in l_copy:
    print(el)
    if el % 2 != 0:
        l.remove(el)
```

---

Для лучшего понимания работы цикла ещё пример:

```
a = [0, 0, 0, 0]
i = 1
for x in a:
    a.insert(i, 7)
    print(x)
    i += 1
```

Этот код отпечатает сперва 0, а потом бесконечно будет выдавать семёрки :)

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
i = 0
for x in a:
    a.insert(i, 7)
    print(x)
    i += 1
```

А вот так семёрок не будет, а будут бесконечные нули (мы постоянно смещаем его вправо новыми семёрками и он постоянно оказывается следующим элементом по индексу).

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все стало на свои места!

Comment: `бесконечно будет выдавать семёрки` только если у нас будет бесконечно памяти

Answer (score 1):

Не удаляй элементы пока проходишь по списку. Используй списковое включение для создания нового списка с элементами которые удовлетворяют нужному тебе условию.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [el for el in a if el%2 == 0]
print (b)
```